# How to sort by fields other than date_modified in SurveyMonkey v3 responses/bulk

Tags: surveymonkey

The [documentation for the SurveyMonkey API version 3 responses/bulk service](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-responses-bulk) says we can pass in a sort_order and sort_by. This works great when I pass in date_modified as the sort_by. But if I pass in any other field (date_created, id, recipient_id), I get back "HTTP 400, Bad Request, Invalid URL Parameters".

My concern is since this is a paged service that we'll have to call multiple times to get all of the responses, if the responses are sorted by date_modified and someone happens to modify a response while we're processing this data and working through the pages, it could cause responses to start moving around to different pages, potentially causing us to miss some (or process some twice). If instead the responses were sorted by date_created, id, recipient_id, or some other field that wouldn't change even if the response is updated, we could be confident that the responses couldn't jump around from page to page while we're processing the data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Currently for fetching responses, date_modified is the only available option for sorting at the moment, I'm not sure when more will be available.

You can [filter responses](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-responses) by many different fields though, so you can use that to reduce the responses returned to a subset you want.

Comment: I don't think the filtering addresses my concern that responses can move around between pages if the date_modified changes during processing. For now I'm mitigating this by pulling back 100 responses per page (the allowed max), and usually we won't have that many, so we'll only have one page. I was thinking perhaps by default it was sorted by date_created, but I did some tests with SoapUI and found that doesn't appear to be the case.